# multi value parameter in SSRS 2012

Tags: reporting-services

I need help to modify an existing `ssrs` report. Currently the end user can only select a single value from the `pFiscalMonth` parameter to view the report. The users now requested to modify the report to allow them to select more than one month to view the report.

The main report data set is a very long query: CTE join other tables. I modified this main report data set where clause as below:

```
WITH FinanceReportSchedule AS(SELECT 52 AS[FinanceRepor ScheduleSK], 2015 AS FiscalYear, 1 AS FiscalMonth, '2014-04-30 00:00:00' AS[Mon hEndDate],
    '2014-05-12 00:00:00' AS PayrollFinalDate, 12 AS PayrollFinalDayCount, '2014-05-16 00:00:00' AS RevExpPreliminaryDate,
    16 AS RevExpPreliminaryDayCount, '2014-05-26 00:00:00' AS RevExpFinalDate, 26 AS RevExpFinalDayCount
     UNION ALL
        SELECT 53 AS Expr1, 2015 AS Expr2, 2 AS Expr3, '2014-05-31 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2014-06-11 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 11 AS Expr6,
                            '2014-06-17 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 17 AS Expr8, '2014-06-24 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 24 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 54 AS Expr1, 2015 AS Expr2, 3 AS Expr3, '2014-06-30 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2014-07-11 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 11 AS Expr6,
                            '2014-07-17 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 17 AS Expr8, '2014-07-24 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 24 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 55 AS Expr1, 2015 AS Expr2, 4 AS Expr3, '2014-07-31 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2014-08-13 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 13 AS Expr6,
                            '2014-08-19 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 19 AS Expr8, '2014-08-26 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 26 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 56 AS Expr1, 2015 AS Expr2, 5 AS Expr3, '2014-08-31 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2014-09-11 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 11 AS Expr6,
                            '2014-09-17 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 17 AS Expr8, '2014-09-24 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 24 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 57 AS Expr1, 2015 AS Expr2, 6 AS Expr3, '2014-09-30 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2014-10-10 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 10 AS Expr6,
                            '2014-10-17 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 17 AS Expr8, '2014-10-24 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 24 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 58 AS Expr1, 2015 AS Expr2, 7 AS Expr3, '2014-10-31 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2014-11-12 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 12 AS Expr6,
                            '2014-11-18 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 18 AS Expr8, '2014-11-25 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 25 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 59 AS Expr1, 2015 AS Expr2, 8 AS Expr3, '2014-11-30 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2014-12-10 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 10 AS Expr6,
                            '2014-12-16 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 16 AS Expr8, '2014-12-23 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 23 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 60 AS Expr1, 2015 AS Expr2, 9 AS Expr3, '2014-12-31 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2015-01-13 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 13 AS Expr6,
                            '2015-01-19 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 19 AS Expr8, '2015-01-26 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 26 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 61 AS Expr1, 2015 AS Expr2, 10 AS Expr3, '2015-01-31 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2015-02-11 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 11 AS Expr6,
                            '2015-02-18 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 18 AS Expr8, '2015-02-25 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 25 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 62 AS Expr1, 2015 AS Expr2, 11 AS Expr3, '2015-02-28 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2015-03-10 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 10 AS Expr6,
                            '2015-03-16 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 16 AS Expr8, '2015-03-23 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 23 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 63 AS Expr1, 2015 AS Expr2, 12 AS Expr3, '2015-03-31 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2015-04-09 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 9 AS Expr6,
                            '2015-04-15 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 15 AS Expr8, '2015-05-15 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 45 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 64 AS Expr1, 2016 AS Expr2, 1 AS Expr3, '2015-04-30 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2015-05-11 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 11 AS Expr6,
                            '2015-05-18 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 18 AS Expr8, '2015-05-25 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 25 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 65 AS Expr1, 2016 AS Expr2, 2 AS Expr3, '2015-05-31 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2015-06-09 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 9 AS Expr6,
                            '2015-06-15 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 15 AS Expr8, '2015-06-22 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 22 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 66 AS Expr1, 2016 AS Expr2, 3 AS Expr3, '2015-06-30 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2015-07-10 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 10 AS Expr6,
                            '2015-07-16 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 16 AS Expr8, '2015-07-23 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 23 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 67 AS Expr1, 2016 AS Expr2, 4 AS Expr3, '2015-07-31 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2015-08-12 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 12 AS Expr6,
                            '2015-08-18 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 18 AS Expr8, '2015-08-25 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 25 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 68 AS Expr1, 2016 AS Expr2, 5 AS Expr3, '2015-08-31 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2015-09-10 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 10 AS Expr6,
                            '2015-09-16 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 16 AS Expr8, '2015-09-23 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 23 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 69 AS Expr1, 2016 AS Expr2, 6 AS Expr3, '2015-09-30 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2015-10-12 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 12 AS Expr6,
                            '2015-10-16 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 16 AS Expr8, '2015-10-23 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 23 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 70 AS Expr1, 2016 AS Expr2, 7 AS Expr3, '2015-10-31 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2015-11-10 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 10 AS Expr6,
                            '2015-11-16 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 16 AS Expr8, '2015-11-23 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 23 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 71 AS Expr1, 2016 AS Expr2, 8 AS Expr3, '2015-11-30 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2015-12-09 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 9 AS Expr6,
                            '2015-12-15 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 15 AS Expr8, '2015-12-22 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 22 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 72 AS Expr1, 2016 AS Expr2, 9 AS Expr3, '2015-12-31 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2016-01-13 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 13 AS Expr6,
                            '2016-01-19 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 19 AS Expr8, '2016-01-26 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 26 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 73 AS Expr1, 2016 AS Expr2, 10 AS Expr3, '2016-01-31 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2016-02-09 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 9 AS Expr6,
                            '2016-02-15 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 15 AS Expr8, '2016-02-22 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 22 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 74 AS Expr1, 2016 AS Expr2, 11 AS Expr3, '2016-02-29 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2016-03-09 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 9 AS Expr6,
                            '2016-03-15 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 15 AS Expr8, '2016-03-22 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 22 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 75 AS Expr1, 2016 AS Expr2, 12 AS Expr3, '2016-03-31 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2016-04-13 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 13 AS Expr6,
                            '2016-04-15 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 15 AS Expr8, '2016-05-17 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 47 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 76 AS Expr1, 2017 AS Expr2, 1 AS Expr3, '2016-04-30 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2016-05-12 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 12 AS Expr6,
                            '2016-05-16 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 16 AS Expr8, '2016-05-26 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 26 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 77 AS Expr1, 2017 AS Expr2, 2 AS Expr3, '2016-05-31 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2016-06-11 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 11 AS Expr6,
                            '2016-06-17 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 17 AS Expr8, '2016-06-24 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 24 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 78 AS Expr1, 2017 AS Expr2, 3 AS Expr3, '2016-06-30 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2016-07-11 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 11 AS Expr6,
                            '2016-07-17 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 17 AS Expr8, '2016-07-24 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 24 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 79 AS Expr1, 2017 AS Expr2, 4 AS Expr3, '2016-07-31 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2016-08-13 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 13 AS Expr6,
                            '2016-08-19 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 19 AS Expr8, '2016-08-26 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 26 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 80 AS Expr1, 2017 AS Expr2, 5 AS Expr3, '2016-08-31 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2016-09-11 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 11 AS Expr6,
                            '2016-09-17 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 17 AS Expr8, '2016-09-24 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 24 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 81 AS Expr1, 2017 AS Expr2, 6 AS Expr3, '2016-09-30 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2016-10-10 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 10 AS Expr6,
                            '2016-10-17 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 17 AS Expr8, '2016-10-24 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 24 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 82 AS Expr1, 2017 AS Expr2, 7 AS Expr3, '2016-10-31 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2016-11-12 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 12 AS Expr6,
                            '2016-11-18 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 18 AS Expr8, '2016-11-25 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 25 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 83 AS Expr1, 2017 AS Expr2, 8 AS Expr3, '2016-11-30 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2016-12-10 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 10 AS Expr6,
                            '2016-12-16 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 16 AS Expr8, '2016-12-23 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 23 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 84 AS Expr1, 2017 AS Expr2, 9 AS Expr3, '2016-12-31 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2017-01-13 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 13 AS Expr6,
                            '2017-01-19 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 19 AS Expr8, '2017-01-26 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 26 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 85 AS Expr1, 2017 AS Expr2, 10 AS Expr3, '2017-01-31 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2017-02-11 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 11 AS Expr6,
                            '2017-02-18 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 18 AS Expr8, '2017-02-25 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 25 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 86 AS Expr1, 2017 AS Expr2, 11 AS Expr3, '2017-02-28 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2017-03-10 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 10 AS Expr6,
                            '2017-03-16 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 16 AS Expr8, '2017-03-23 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 23 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 87 AS Expr1, 2017 AS Expr2, 12 AS Expr3, '2017-03-31 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2017-04-09 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 9 AS Expr6,
                            '2017-04-15 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 15 AS Expr8, '2017-05-15 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 15 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 88 AS Expr1, 2018 AS Expr2, 1 AS Expr3, '2017-04-30 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2017-05-11 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 11 AS Expr6,
                            '2017-05-18 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 18 AS Expr8, '2017-05-25 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 25 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 89 AS Expr1, 2018 AS Expr2, 2 AS Expr3, '2017-05-31 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2017-06-09 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 9 AS Expr6,
                            '2017-06-15 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 15 AS Expr8, '2017-06-22 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 22 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 90 AS Expr1, 2018 AS Expr2, 3 AS Expr3, '2017-06-30 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2017-07-10 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 10 AS Expr6,
                            '2017-07-16 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 16 AS Expr8, '2017-07-23 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 23 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 91 AS Expr1, 2018 AS Expr2, 4 AS Expr3, '2017-07-31 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2017-08-12 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 12 AS Expr6,
                            '2017-08-18 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 18 AS Expr8, '2017-08-25 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 25 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 92 AS Expr1, 2018 AS Expr2, 5 AS Expr3, '2017-08-31 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2017-09-10 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 10 AS Expr6,
                            '2017-09-16 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 16 AS Expr8, '2017-09-23 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 23 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 93 AS Expr1, 2018 AS Expr2, 6 AS Expr3, '2017-09-30 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2017-10-12 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 12 AS Expr6,
                            '2017-10-16 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 16 AS Expr8, '2017-10-23 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 23 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 94 AS Expr1, 2018 AS Expr2, 7 AS Expr3, '2017-10-31 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2017-11-10 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 10 AS Expr6,
                            '2017-11-16 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 16 AS Expr8, '2017-11-23 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 23 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 95 AS Expr1, 2018 AS Expr2, 8 AS Expr3, '2017-11-30 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2017-12-09 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 9 AS Expr6,
                            '2017-12-15 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 15 AS Expr8, '2017-12-22 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 22 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 96 AS Expr1, 2018 AS Expr2, 9 AS Expr3, '2017-12-31 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2018-01-13 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 13 AS Expr6,
                            '2018-01-19 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 19 AS Expr8, '2018-01-26 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 26 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 97 AS Expr1, 2018 AS Expr2, 10 AS Expr3, '2018-01-31 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2018-02-09 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 9 AS Expr6,
                            '2018-02-15 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 15 AS Expr8, '2018-02-22 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 22 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 98 AS Expr1, 2018 AS Expr2, 11 AS Expr3, '2018-02-28 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2018-03-09 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 9 AS Expr6,
                            '2018-03-15 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 15 AS Expr8, '2018-03-22 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 22 AS Expr10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 99 AS Expr1, 2018 AS Expr2, 12 AS Expr3, '2018-03-31 00:00:00' AS Expr4, '2018-04-13 00:00:00' AS Expr5, 13 AS Expr6,
                            '2018-04-15 00:00:00' AS Expr7, 15 AS Expr8, '2018-05-17 00:00:00' AS Expr9, 17 AS Expr10)
    SELECT aa.Union_code, aa.WorkedHrs, aa.Pay_Class, aa.PType, aa.Amount, aa.FiscalYear, aa.FiscalPeriod, aa.FiscalYearReportName, aa.Employee, bb.LastName, bb.FirstName,
                      cc.PayClassDesc, ff.AU, ff.Owner, ff.FirstName AS AUOwnerFirstName, ff.LastName AS AUOwnerLastName, ff.Program, ee.PersonResponsible, dd.Level9Code,
                      dd.Level9Name, bb.POSITION, Dim_Pay_Position.DESCRIPTION, CASE WHEN getdate() >= PayrollFinalDate THEN 'Final' ELSE 'No Available' END AS ReportStatus
    FROM(SELECT Union_code, WorkedHrs, Pay_Class, PType, Amount, FiscalYear, FiscalPeriod, FiscalYearReportName, Employee, EmployeeSK, CostCenterSK, CDateSK
                      FROM      Fact_Pay_AUreport AS a
                      WHERE   (AUcode = @pCostCentre) AND(FiscalYear = @pFiscalYear) AND**(FiscalPeriod IN(@pFiscalMonth))** AS aa INNER JOIN
                   FinanceReportSchedule AS SC ON SC.FiscalYear = aa.FiscalYear AND SC.FiscalMonth = aa.FiscalPeriod AND GETDATE() >= SC.PayrollFinalDate INNER JOIN
                   Dim_PayReport_Employee AS bb ON aa.EmployeeSK = bb.EmployeeSK INNER JOIN
                   Dim_Pay_PayClass AS cc ON aa.Pay_Class = cc.PayClassCode INNER JOIN

                   HierarchyCostCentre AS dd ON aa.CostCenterSK = dd.CostCentreSK INNER JOIN

                   DimCostCentre AS ee ON aa.CostCenterSK = ee.CostCentreSK INNER JOIN

                   DimSigningAuthority AS ff ON ee.Code = ff.AU INNER JOIN

                   Dim_Pay_Position ON bb.POSITION = Dim_Pay_Position.POSITION


however when i tried to execute modified query in query designer got error message said IN clause is not compatible with the query.

Here is the data set query for this @pFiscalMonth parameter:


SELECT DISTINCT Fact_Pay_AUreport.FiscalPeriod, DimDate.MonthName, Fact_Pay_AUreport.FiscalYear
FROM            Fact_Pay_AUreport INNER JOIN
                      DimDate ON Fact_Pay_AUreport.CDateSK = DimDate.DateSK
WHERE        (Fact_Pay_AUreport.FiscalYear = 2014)
ORDER BY Fact_Pay_AUreport.FiscalPeriod
```

By the way, I already set parameter property: available value: get value from query; label name: MonthName; value: MonthName

Can someone give me some idea how to fix this error? should I use split function? I checked database there is no split function available. probably need to create one if it's necessary.

Comment: You have not included the error message that you are receiving.  Ugly as your query is, the syntax looks fine for a multi valued parameter to work.  What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Thanks. This problem is solved. However I got another problem from another report. Please see below.

Comment: Made code a bit easier to read

Answer (score 0):

I think you need another ) after `(FiscalPeriod IN (@pFiscalMonth))`. There is no closing to the parentheses after `FROM(`, before `AS aa`.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it tomorrow then let you know whether it works.

Comment: Hi Adam, you are right. I forgot to put another ) The problem is solved.

Comment: Please see my another problem as above. Thanks.